# Is there a way to increase the length of dashes in \borderline{width}{offset}{dashed}?

Tags: tcolorbox, border

Is there a way to increase the length of dashes in `\tcolorbox\borderline{width}{offset}{dashed}`?
Here's some base code that doesn't work

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    height= \textheight,
    frame hidden,
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{black,dashed}]%put dashlength=20??

Some text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use `dash pattern`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,
    height= \textheight,
    frame hidden,
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{black,dash pattern=on15 off12}]

Some text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can't find  `dash pattern` in tcolorbox 4.42 manual. Can you please redirect me to your source or some reference so I may understand the meaning of `onX offY`?

Comment: @lineage This is a tikz/pgf key, See page 175 of pgfmanual 3.1.8.